# Executing Javascript trigger from .net codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm attempting to execute a trigger from .net codebehind.
What normally happens is, you click on a tab which highlights the tab, then executes some javascript to make certain divs visible.

Currently, the code I've written will highlight the tab, but the divs are not made visible.

```
 if (Request.QueryString["ID"] == "56")
        {
            ltrClassName.Text = "active";

            StringBuilder jscript = new StringBuilder();
            jscript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function PremiumServicesClick() {");
            jscript.Append("$('#PremiumServicesTab').trigger('click');");
            jscript.Append("})");
            jscript.Append("</script>");
        }
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "0", "PremiumServicesClick()", true);
```

I have this code running in the Page_Load event.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after }) in the 3rd Append() call.

Comment: Do you do anything with the string you build in the `jscript` StringBuilder?

Comment: Also, make sure #PremiumServicesTab is the real ID. If PremiumServicesTab is a Sever side control, you'll need PremiumServicesTab.ClientID (C#). The Register script has to register the whole jscript string, or it won't be written to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle that click event client-side, in javascript, not server-side.
If you really must do a postback you could put some code in the .aspx file, which sets the required properties to the html elements as needed.

If your tabs and/or divs belong to server side controls, most certainly you can edit those controls' properties accordingly.

Edit (requested example):

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px; <%=Page.IsPostBack ? "background-color: red;" : "" %>">

</div>
```

The above code colors the div into red only if the page load is caused by a postback. Of course, you can replace the condition with anything that suits you and the attribute(s) you add/replace. This way, your html is conditioned by server-side variables (whichever you want, however you want).

Comment: Because of cms limitations, this needs to be done server-side--this code needs to be executed automatically based on the querystring parameter. Please provide an example of 'you could put some code in the .aspx file, which sets the required properties to the html elements as needed'

Comment: As an extra hint to the code example, in the condition you can also check the posted parameters (in case you need to know some value which got changed)

Comment: Not sure if I'm stating my idea clear enough, but I find the idea of sending some html to the client and the instructions on how to modify it (the javascript) a non sense, when you could just send him the html properly formed in the first place.